# what exactly happens in this method?

Tags: java

I want to make a method which returns an array of buttons containing the letter of them . I wrote the method but I'm not sure what exactly happens?

```
public JButton [] button(){
    JButton [] button = null ;
    for(int i = 0 ;i<26 ;i++){
        String letter  = String.valueOf((char)(i + 'A'));
        button[i] = new JButton(letter);
    }
    return  button() ;
}
```

Comment: you are calling the function again (recursion). assuming everything else is correct, do `return button;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the array first as following

```
JButton [] button = new JButton[26];  // see null is removed.
```

and return properly

```
return button; // removed paranthesis
```

Answer (score 4):

You are calling the method recursively and indefinitely:

```
return button() ;
```

That should be:

```
return button;
```

Best would be avoiding naming methods and variables confusingly. Also, you'll need to initialize the button array properly:

```
JButton[] button = new JButton[26];
```

Comment: The instruction `button[i]=new JButton(letter)` will cause an NPE, or at least an OutOfBoundException

Comment: @Julien Thanks, I somehow missed that. Added it to the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You will get a NullPointerException because your array is not initialised:

`JButton [] button = new JButton[26];`

And at your return statement you call the method again which will cause an infinite loop.

```
return button; // removed paranthesis
```

This will return the array you create in the loop.

Your code should look like this:

```
public JButton [] button(){
    JButton [] button = new JButton[26];
    for(int i = 0 ;i<26 ;i++){
        String letter  = String.valueOf((char)(i + 'A'));
        buttons[i] = new JButton(letter);
    }
    return button;
}
```

To your question what the code does:

It creates an array of JButtons labeled with one letter from `A` to `Z`